# Lookup list using wild cards

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I'll start by describing my data

```
List1:
Company           Result
---------
Company1 (1234)   1
Company1 (1445)   1
Company3blabla    2
Company4          0

LookupList:
Company     Index
------------------
*Company1*    1
*Company3*    2
```

I'm trying to find a formula that will search for each Company in List1 if it **contains** a match from LookupList (hence the presence of * wild cards), and if so, it would return the corresponding index value, as shown in the Result column.

So far I got a formula that can return 1 if there's a match, and 0 if not, but I don't know how to get the index value from there:

{=MAX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('LookupList'!$A$1:$A$2,List1[[#This Row],[Company]]))+0)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the wildcards (SEARCH automatically searches within other text anyway) so you can remove those and use this formula in result column to get the INDEX value

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH('LookupList'!$A$1:$A$2,List1[[#This Row],[Company]]),'LookupList'!$B$1:$B$2),"")`

That will give you a blank if there is no match - change the "" at the end to text like "No match" if required

Comment: This works great! The only thing was that it returned the Company value instead of index. To get the index I had to reference col B in the las argument of the lookup: =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH('LookupList'!$A$1:$A$2,List1[[#This Row],[Company]]),'LookupList'!$B$1:$B$2),"")